# Unexpected implicit resolution based on inference from return type

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit, return-type, scalaz

Given a typeclass where instance selection should be performed based on the return type:

```
case class Monoid[A](m0: A) // We only care about the zero here
implicit def s[T] : Monoid[Set[T]] = Monoid(Set.empty[T])
implicit def l[T] : Monoid[List[T]] = Monoid(List.empty[T])
def mzero[A](implicit m: Monoid[A]) : A = m.m0
```

why does Scala (2.11.6) fail to resolve the proper instance:

```
scala> mzero : List[Int]
<console>:24: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method s of type [T]=> Monoid[Set[T]]
 and method l of type [T]=> Monoid[List[T]]
 match expected type Monoid[A]
              mzero : List[Int]
              ^
```

when it has no problems finding an implicit based on the return type when using the **implicitly** function (we redefine it here as **i** to illustrate how similar it is to **mzero**)

```
def i[A](implicit a : A) : A = a
scala> i : Monoid[List[Int]]
res18: Monoid[List[Int]] = Monoid(List())
```

The `Monoid[A]`, instead of `Monoid[List[Int]]` in the error message is puzzling.

I would assume many scalaz contributors to be familiar with this problem as it seems to limit the convenience of typeclasses in scala.

EDIT: I'm looking into getting this working without forgoing type inference. Otherwise I'd like understand why that's not possible. If this limitation is documented as a Scala issue, I could not find it.

Comment: The limits of Scala's ability to use expected return types to guide inference of type parameters when implicits are involved are incredibly confusing, so everybody just writes `mzero[List[Int]]`.

Comment: As some workaround you can get away by redefining `mzero` as `def mzero[A](implicit m: Monoid[_<:A]) : A = m.m0`. Ut I'd personnaly go with `mzero[List[Int]]` as Travis Brown mentioned.

Comment: Impressive and surprising. Thanks! Any explanation? This appears to be relaxing the type and obtaining fewer matches!

Comment: Sorry but no, I have no explanation of this behavior. It's just that experience told me to try to make `Monoid` covariant, which indeed makes the code compile. As you probably cannot make it covariant (given that a complete definition of `Monoid` would have occurences of `A` in contravariant position), the next best thing is to try to emulate this on `mzero` alone by using an existential type, giving `def mzero[A](implicit m: Monoid[_<:A])`. I would definitely be interested in getting an explanation of this oddness myself.

Answer (score 1):

1) After rewriting your code as follows:

```
case class Monoid[A](m0: A) // We only care about the zero here
implicit def s[T] : Monoid[Set[T]] = Monoid(Set.empty[T])
implicit def l[T] : Monoid[List[T]] = Monoid(List.empty[T])
def mzero[A]()(implicit m: Monoid[A]) : A = m.m0

val zero = mzero[List[Int]]()
val zero2: List[Int] = mzero()
```

then becomes clearly why that works so.

2) After you had to set mzero as `def mzero[A]()(implicit m: Monoid[_ <: A]) : A = m.m0` then you enabled additional type inference to resolve existencial type. Compiler got actual type from required return type. 
You could check it with `def mzero[A <: B, B]()(implicit m: Monoid[A]) : A = m.m0` if you want.

3) Of course all that behaviour is just subtleties of compiler and I not think that such partial cases really required deep understanding.